# Need to click on a widget to give it focus in Power BI Embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI embedded report, embedded in my web app.

While the report is working as expected I find that I need to click on a widget within the report before being able to click on the items within the widget.

So for example I have a slicer containing a list of names. When I first click on the slicer, it selects the slicer but does not drop down the list of names, the next click allows me to see the list of names.

Is there anything I can do to change this behaviour, such that the first click on the slicer shows the list of names available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is caused by me requesting the report in mobile view. Switching to desktop view stop the second click issue.

I had chosen mobile view, as this view allowed the UI to switch between views (landscape/portrait) dynamically without having to reload the report. In desktop view if the user resizes the browser page, the report shrinks shrinks rather than switch between views.